# Collapse a pandas data frame of words into sentences

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, data-cleaning

My goal is to take a dataframe composed of words and tags, and collapse it into a dataframe composed of sentences and a list of tags.

Sample input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('Effect', 'O'),
               ('of', 'O'),
               ('ginseng', 'i'),
               ('extract', 'i'),
               ('supplementation', 'i'),
               ('on', 'O'),
               ('testicular', 'o'),
               ('functions', 'o'),
               ('in', 'O'),
               ('diabetic', 'p'),
               ('rats', 'p'),
               ('.', 'p'),
               ('OBJECTIVE', 'O'),
               ('It', 'O'),
               ('was', 'O')],
               columns=('token', 'annotation'))
```

Goal output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('Effect of ginseng extract supplementation on testicular functions in diabetic rats.', \ 
                     ['O','O','i','i','i','O','o','o','O','p','p','p','O','O','O']),
                   ('OBJECTIVE It was', ['O','O','O'])],
                   columns=('token', 'annotation'))
```

Sorry for the goofy example - that really is the first 15 rows of this dataset!!

Any ideas of how to compress the rows of words into rows of sentences would be much appreciated.

Comment: are you looking a solution for your particular example or a general case solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
new_df = (df.groupby(df['token'].eq('.').shift(fill_value=False).cumsum(),
        as_index=False)
            .agg({'token' : ' '.join, 'annotation': list}))
print(new_df)
                                               token  \
0  Effect of ginseng extract supplementation on t...   
1                                   OBJECTIVE It was   

                             annotation  
0  [O, O, i, i, i, O, o, o, O, p, p, p]  
1                             [O, O, O]
```

If you don't want include the last point:

```
m = df['token'].eq('.')
new_df = (df.groupby(m.shift(fill_value=False).cumsum().loc[~m],as_index=False)
            .agg({'token' : ' '.join, 'annotation': list}))
```

Comment: This works great - thanks!!  Learning a lot about pandas (and a lot more than I wanted to know about diabetic rats!)